# How to write unit test cases for different screen sizes?

Tags: unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have two buttons to display based on the screen size(for medium screen one button and another button for other screens). I'm using Material UI's MediaQuery and theme.breakpoints to define the screen size.

This is my UI code and I'm using *Typescript in React*.

```js
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export default function SimpleCard() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMd = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only("md"));

  return (
    <div>
      {isMd ? (
        <Button
          data-testid="mediumScreenButton"
          onClick={() => console.log("medium")}
        >
          medium screen
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Button
          data-testid="otherScreenButton"
          onClick={() => console.log("other")}
        >
          Other screen
        </Button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my test code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, screen, waitFor, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import Demo from './Demo'

beforeEach(() =>
{
  window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
  window.HTMLDivElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = jest.fn();

  // window.matchMedia('(max-width: 999px)');

});

describe('To test cond. for screen sizes', () =>
{
  afterEach(cleanup);

  it('Medium screen', async () =>
  {
    const { container } = render(<Demo />)

    const mediumScreenButton = screen.getByTestId('mediumScreenButton');
    fireEvent.click(mediumScreenButton);

    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();

  });

});
```

I don't understand how to **set the screen size to medium in my test file** so that my test case will pass. But right now, the test case is failing as "unable to find element with data testid mediumScreenButton  ".
Can someone help me in solving this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Mui [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/#testing) have some example on how do to it.

> You need an implementation of matchMedia in your test environment.
> For instance, jsdom doesn't support it yet. You should polyfill it. Using `css-mediaquery` to emulate it is recommended.

So first you need to install `css-mediaquery`:

```sh
npm install css-mediaquery
// OR
yarn add css-mediaquery
```

And your test could be:

```js
import mediaQuery from "css-mediaquery";
import Demo from './Demo'

const createMatchMedia = (width) => (query) => ({
  matches: mediaQuery.match(query, { width }),
  addListener: () => {},
  removeListener: () => {}
});

describe("Media Test", () => {
  it("Desktop Test", async () => {
    window.matchMedia = createMatchMedia(1000);

    render(<Demo />);

    const buttonEl = screen.getByRole("button");

    expect(buttonEl).toHaveTextContent("medium screen");
  });

  it("Mobile Test", async () => {
    window.matchMedia = createMatchMedia(200);

    render(<Demo />);

    const buttonEl = screen.getByRole("button");

    expect(buttonEl).toHaveTextContent("Other screen");
  });
});
```

* A tip about your code:

Avoid use `getByTestId` to find elements with `testing-library`. In their documents has a query priority recommendation, as you can check [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#priority). So, in your case you can use `getByRole('button')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Luis. Is there any other fix without installing any library.

Comment: Probably yes, but i don´t know how. What you can do is go to the `css-mediaquery` github page and check out how they do that.

Comment: I think you could just use `window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)")` as seen here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Typescript in my project. The below code is worked for me. Thanks to @Luis for the hint.

install `css-mediaquery`

```bash
npm install css-mediaquery
```

add this function in your test file

```js
function createMatchMedia(width) {
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
      matches: mediaQuery.match(query, { width }),
      media: query,
      onchange: null,
      addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
      dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
    })),
  });
};
```

Finally place this in your test case (it)

```js
createMatchMedia('999px');
```

Overall test code would be

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, screen, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import Demo from './Demo';
import mediaQuery from 'css-mediaquery'; // install this package

function createMatchMedia(width) {
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
      matches: mediaQuery.match(query, { width }),
      media: query,
      onchange: null,
      addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
      dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
    })),
  });
};

beforeEach(() => {
  window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
  window.HTMLDivElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = jest.fn();
});

describe('To test cond. for screen sizes', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);

  it('Medium screen', async () => {
    createMatchMedia('999px');
    const { container } = render(<Demo />);

    const mediumScreenButton = screen.getByTestId('mediumScreenButton');
    fireEvent.click(mediumScreenButton);

    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();

  });
});
```