# What's the screen size react testing is using when doing tests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

What's the screen size react testing is using when doing tests, I couldn't find any information about it from the docs?

```
  const onPageChange = jest.fn();

  test("renders correctly", () => {
    render(
      <Sidebar page="Profiili" onPageChange={onPageChange} />
    );
    expect(screen.getByText("Profile")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText("Jobs")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText("Schedule")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText("Settings")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByAltText("Hamburger icon")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Comment: I don't think there is one per se. The general practice when testing how things are at certain breakpoints is to polyfill CSS media queries and/or stub out the window resize event handlers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72747196/how-to-write-unit-test-cases-for-different-screen-sizes-using-react-testing-libr

Comment: Okay, but I was wondering how to test if a component renders correctly, when the appearance of the component is different depending on the screen size? @JaredSmith

Comment: The way I suggested in my previous comment? If you're checking the screen size using media queries use the jsdom media queries polyfill. If you're checking e.g. `window.screen.width` then mock it with whatever value you want for the current test.

Comment: Could you give me an example? @JaredSmith

Comment: Of which one? Can you post some code that shows what you're trying to do?

Comment: I posted the code I currently have. When the page is 600px or wider, then there's no hamburger icon visible. @JaredSmith

Comment: Is this JSDOM? There's no screen, no page, no width.

Comment: I'm using react testing library, I'm not sure what you mean with JSDOM? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Well you've tagged this [tag:jestjs], so is your `testEnvironment: "jsdom"` (that's the setup from CRA, for example)? Most likely you're rendering your components in a _simulation_ of a browser page, so there is no actual width.

Comment: That isn't nearly enough code for us to help you: we'd need a minimal repro case with a component that shows how you're checking the screen with. Jonrsharpe is also correct: RTL/jest is using a node.js DOM implementation to simulate a browser (jsdom), there is no screen.